# Visual Studio C# Tab Auto Formatting Going Backwards

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autoformatting

After searching for a very very long time, I still haven't found an answer. Basically anytime anything is done with tabs in Visual Studio in C#, things go very badly (see attached gifs, note that the two initial tabs are for a namespace and class). These issues only happen in C# as far as I can tell, as I've used Visual Studio as my main IDE for C++ development and haven't had these sorts of issues. I've attached what I think are relevant settings screenshots.

In the attached gifs, there is only one line that the bug is shown on, but things get very nasty if I attempt to copy multiple lines...

Any help would be massively appreciated!

[image: indenting]

[image: adaptive formatting]

[image: brackets]

[image: copy paste]

[image: comment uncomment]

Comment: What happens if you reset the settings?

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is your issue ...

But starting with VS2019 an .editorconfig file can be generated and its settings saved to the project. I would check and see if one exists.
[image]
[Code style rule options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Unfortunately not my problem...made a new blank project on the Desktop and the same issue still occurs. :/

Comment: I was checking VS2019 and VS2022 and neither one act like what your showing.

Comment: Just on a whim...try changing the indention to Block or None...save  and close. Relaunch VS and change it back to smart and save and close.

Comment: I have no idea why, but that worked...must be a weird bug? How'd you think to do this? Writing half a program with this issue was a nightmare.

Thank you!